# HTML link with a php action

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink

I am creating a website that stores information of homes like address, city etc. I got the upload to database part done and I got the search the database and display the information done.

But now my plan with that is you get the search results and from there your suppose to get the option to view the full profile of that home via link. Displaying the full profile with the information gathered from the database is already done through a separate php file. Now when I link the php file it will only display the last column in the database. How can I link it so when I click on "view full profile" it will connect to the correct data/profile that corresponds to the different address or price. Or if i cant use an html link what can I use? Is that impossible?

here is the code that displays the search results I have successfully been able to search the database and display it

```
    <?php
if($sql->num_rows){
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo '<div id="listing">
                    <div id="propertyImage"> 
                        <img src="images/'.$row['imageName1'].'" width="200" height="150" alt=""/> 
                    </div>

                    <div id="basicInfo">
                    <h2>$'.$row['Price'].'</h2>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;"># '.$row['StreetAddress'].', '.$row['City'].', BC</p>
                    <p>'.$row['NumBed'].' Bedrooms | '.$row['NumBath'].' Bathrooms | '.$row['Property'].'</p>
                    <br>
                    <p><a href="outputtest.php" class="link2">View Full Details</a> | <a href="services/services.html" class="link2">Get Directions</a>

                    </div>
                </div>';

        height="150" alt=""/>';


    }
}
else
{
echo '<h2>0 Search Results</h2>';
}
?>
```

Here is the php to display the information outputtest.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","31588patrick");
@mysql_select_db("test") or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM propertyinfo";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();



$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$varStreetAddress=mysql_result($result,$i,"StreetAddress");
$varCity=mysql_result($result,$i,"City");
$varProperty=mysql_result($result,$i,"Property");
$varNumBed=mysql_result($result,$i,"NumBed");
$varNumBath=mysql_result($result,$i,"NumBath");
$varPrice=mysql_result($result,$i,"Price");
$varEmail=mysql_result($result,$i,"Email");
$varPhone=mysql_result($result,$i,"Phone");
$varUtilities=mysql_result($result,$i,"utilities");
$varTermLease=mysql_result($result,$i,"TermLease");
$varNotes=mysql_result($result,$i,"Notes");
$image1=mysql_result($result,$i,"imageName1");
$image2=mysql_result($result,$i,"imageName2");
$image3=mysql_result($result,$i,"imageName3");
$image4=mysql_result($result,$i,"imageName4");



$i++;
}

?> html code will go after this
```

Thanks

edit its working

```
    <?php

////////////using mysqli to connect with database

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","31588patrick", "test");
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
///////////set variables
$record_id = $_GET['record_id'];

$sql = $mysqli->query("select * from propertyinfo where StreetAddress like '%$record_id%'");

if($sql === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling

}


if($sql->num_rows){
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $varStreetAddress=$row['StreetAddress'];
        $varCity=$row['City'];
        $varProperty=$row['Property'];
        $varNumBed=$row['NumBed'];
        $varNumBath=$row['NumBath'];
        $varPrice=$row['Price'];
        $varEmail=$row['Email'];
        $varPhone=$row['Phone'];
        $varUtilities=$row['utilities'];
        $varTermLease=$row['TermLease'];
        $varNotes=$row['Notes'];
        $image1=$row['imageName1'];
        $image2=$row['imageName2'];
        $image3=$row['imageName3'];
        $image4=$row['imageName4'];

        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Code is worth a 1000 words.

Comment: Try to simplify your question, you will get better answers fast

Answer (score 0):

If the link you are using is only fetching the last record in the database table, then the underlying query that is used must be fetching the last record instead of the intended record.  Am I correct in understanding the problem you are having?  That any link you use is just returning the last record in the database?

Posting a code snippet will help the community take a closer look.

in your php file, you run a query for all records, but ...

```
$record_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["record_id"]);
$query="SELECT * FROM propertyinfo WHERE id=$record_id";
```

your link needs to attach a parameter that will allow you to query for a specific record.

```
a href="outputtest.php&record_id=8"
```

AND you would also want to check what is in the GET parameter before sticking it into the query!  I know mysql_real_escape_string is outdated.

Comment: Yes and the html link links to the php file that displays the information

Comment: for now i have put this <a href="outputtest.php" class="link2">View Full Details</a>

Comment: you are linking to the same file ever time, outputtest.php .... so there is no difference between any of the links.  Next, we would need to see what happens inside of outputtest.php

Comment: Just added the code for outputtest.php should i make a second output php file specifically for this one?

Comment: Ok I see what  what you mean. I would have to make sure what is in the GET parameter is the address to match what is in the database. Am I right? Also should I change the code in outputtest.php to mysqli if mysql is outdated?

Comment: yes (basically) and yes.  mysqli or PDO prepared statements are the way to go.  You can keep posting comments here, but also don't forget to update the code in your question.  StackOverflow tends to discourage running comment sections :(